# Report layout and datasets

Tags: c#, dataset, rdlc

I'm using VS2013 C# building an application that requires an invoice report. 
 The report needs to have nested  row groups.  I'm not sure if I need to use subreports or group within the parent group.  The datasets for the report are built in code with objects passed to the report form.

I've been trying to get it to work and can't seem to figure it out.  If anybody has any ideas or thoughts I would appreciate it.  Please see the example layout below and if more info is needed I'll be happy to provide it.

```
ACCOUNT 1 (row group)
--------SubAccount1
--------SubAccount2
--------SubAccount3
--------SubAccount4
----Schedule 1 (row group that needs to be related to ACCOUNT 1)
--------Item1
--------Item2
ACCOUNT 2 (row group)
--------SubAccount1
--------SubAccount2
--------SubAccount3
--------SubAccount4
----Schedule 2 (row group that needs to be related to ACCOUNT 2)
--------Item1
--------Item2
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Please provide a [mcve].  We can't help you with your code if there isn't any.

Comment: @MikeH - Thanks for taking the time and I apologize for the incompleteness of my question.  I did finally get it figured out though.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.  It had to do with row grouping but at first I couldn't figure out how to get the report to display how we need.  After playing with it for two days I finally have it.

The 'Account' is the Parent row group.  The 'SubAccounts' is the Details group, nested within the Parent group.  I created another Child row group, 'Schedule', under the 'Account' group, and then created another Child group, 'Item', under the 'Schedule' group.

The dataset that feeds the body section of the report comes from one datatable.  I was trying a separate datatable with the schedule info in it, unsuccessfully using relationships in the dataset, so I couldn't get that to work.  It turns out the solution that worked was the simplest.

The only problem I have now is that extra blank rows are getting added immediately under the 'Account' and 'Schedule' rows.  I guess that should be a separate topic.

Thanks all.